# Assign weight to specific vertices with normalization on

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I am having a quite simple cylinder like shape which is to be deformed by some bones.
The start and end should be undeformed by all other bones and the rest should be distributed evenly.

So after I parented with automatic weights, I select the top and bottom rows with the according bones and assign a weight of 1.0 to them (with either Shift+K or the assign button in the vertex groups).
I would now expect, that those vertices are not weighted in any other bone. But they are.
I know there is "Auto normalize" in the tools (which is checked) but that only seems to work for weight painting and not assigning in the way above.
Am I missing something or is that not possible currently?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3D View > Side Bar > Item > Vertex Weights in edit mode.

Rewrite the group value of active vertex to one and
delete other group values with delete buttons.
Then use the copy button to copy the state of the active vertex to the other selected vertices.
[image]

Comment: My question was more aimed at why the normalization is not working when assigning weights like I did above.
But since it is a possibility to do it, I accepted your answer. Thanks.